# Call python script from web page and get results

Tags: python, cgi

So, my project does a lot of mathematics for the user. It lets them enter equations and then solves them with some fairly complicated items like eigenvalues. I do some of this is javascript, but I have also written a python script utilizing numpy. I would like the user to be able to have the option of having the script on their local machine and then solving the mathematics there instead of on my server.

So, the user would enter an equation and hit enter. The javascript would then call a python script running on the users local machine. The equation is solved there with my code and the result is returned to the web page.

I thought that this would be possible with CGI, but I cannot seem to find clear documentation on how this would be accomplished. Is there a better way?

I do not want to run third party software and I do not want to run the python code in the browser.

Thanks

Comment: The browser itself isn't capable of taking things from a pc directly, without going over the internet for security reasons. The only possible way I can think of would be to have every user host there own server from which your website loads the python code, which would just be plain silly.

Comment: This is sort of what I was thinking actually. The user could spin up their own server on their computer and download the code from my site or I could load it from the browser and run it. My thinking is that users would prefer to run the code on their own machines instead of paying to run it on our servers.

Comment: In that case, I think they would just prefer a small .exe over a website all together. Note that having users download the code is probably at least as expensive (server-wise) as running it, depending on the python code.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: no, this isn't possible.

Sure, they can download your script and run it themselves if they have a compatible version of Python installed, but you won't be able to run it from the browser (that would be a severe security problem!)

Your options are either to write it in JS, or create an API on your server, or find and use an existing API.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers are not able to execute code on a local machine, but you could work around it with downloading the python code and AJAX requests, as implied in your comment. That would require your end users to run a server themselves. 
[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) would then probably be your best option. You'd embed the flask code to run the server inside the python code. Once your mathematics have been executed, make an AJAX request to your website sending the results along.

I personally would advice you to either run all the math in JS, or else serve the python code from your own server.